# Unable to load Fragment inside Main Activity into frame layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I am trying to load fragment into my framelayout "main_container" in my main activity. But the activity is not loading the frame layout inside it. As you can see I have tried to display on frame layout in my activity by giving black background to frame layout. But I am unable to view the frame layout when app is executed. The issue is I am unable to view any component added in activity_main when app is executed in any device.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment(MainActivity.this);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, mainFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(mainFragment.toString());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
   }
}
```

**MainFragment.java**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements MainRecyclerViewAdapter.RecyclerViewClickListener {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ArrayList<DataModel> arrayList;
private LinearLayout mainLayout;
private Context mContext;

public MainFragment(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.main_rv);
    mainLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.ll_fragment_main);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    arrayList.add(new DataModel("Diseases", R.drawable.ic_disease));
    arrayList.add(new DataModel("Diet Plan", R.drawable.ic_diet_plan));
    arrayList.add(new DataModel("Nutritions", R.drawable.ic_nutrition));
    arrayList.add(new DataModel("Food Info", R.drawable.ic_nutrient_sources));

    MainRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new MainRecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), arrayList, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    AutoFitGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new AutoFitGridLayoutManager(getContext(), 500);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view, int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Message.successMessage(mainLayout, "Disease");
            break;
        case 1:
            Message.successMessage(mainLayout, "Diet Plan");
            break;
        case 2:
            Message.successMessage(mainLayout, "Nutritions");
            break;
        case 3:
            Message.successMessage(mainLayout, "Food Info");
            break;
       }
   }
 }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding incorrect onCreate method of the Activity.

Override this-

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

}
```

instead of

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable 
PersistableBundle persistentState)
```